how do I add turn-off to a latching circuit?
so, I made this latch circuit : Falstad Simulator

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
It turns on and stays on. How do I add turning off using single momentary switch?
I tried making an RC switch like this to turn off Q1 base:


If you're talking about a button that disconnects from the rest of circuitry while holding down said button, there's no official name for that. But perhaps something like a "momentary switch, normally closed" is the terminology you can try looking up.

By SW1 you turn on Q1. Add SW2 so that to turn it off.

I want to turn off with a single switch

Are you asking for a single switch that toggles the state of the latch each time it’s operated?

@Frog Yes, I want a momentary button that can press once for on, then hold for off

The reset switch can be inserted to several places. Simply short momentarily the base of Q1 to GND or break the hold feedback otherwise.
I guess you actually do not want to add a separate reset switch, but expect a modification which makes possible to turn the led ON and OFF in turns by pressing successively only button SW1.
It's easy if you accept that the button can be pushed only shortly and one must wait a moment between the pushes:

If the LED has been OFF long enough C1 is fully charged through R4. Push then SW1 shortly. Current from C1 triggers the latch and the LED turns ON. C1 starts to get discharged through R4 and Q1.
When the discharging is completed push again SW1 shortly. Connecting empty C1 to the joint of R5 and R6 breaks the hold feedback and the LED turns OFF.
You still will have some head scratching and also fun when deciding good component values. R6 is there only to prevent burning Q1 with too high current from C1 when the latch is triggered. Start by setting the following values:
R1=4.7 kΩ, R2=1 kΩ, R3=1 kΩ, R4=100 kΩ, R5=10 kΩ, R6=100 Ω, C1=22 µF These are valid for 12V operating voltage.
The LED is above the hold feedback start node to be sure the base of Q1 is pulled to the ground in the OFF state through R6, R5 and R3.
If it must work also with long pushes you need a circuit which has 4 stable states and that means implementing a full T-flip-flop. It needs 4 transistors. To keep it simple consider to use a flip-flop IC in that case. Warning: Logic ICs react very fast. You need a switch debouncing circuit to prevent multiple state transitions when you push the switch.
LATE ADDITION:
Thinking a little more led me to suspect the circuit above and its guessed component values. Fortunately it works at least in simulation.


The relay is 100 ms ON at every 2 second.

I’ll give a partial answer based on some clarification in the comments; the OP wants a single button with press-for-on and hold-for-off functionality.
In essence a solution could be a bistable latch with both set and clear inputs, the ‘clear’ overriding the ‘set’ but delayed by an RC with a suitably long time constant.  I’m not in a position to draw a schematic for such a circuit at the moment, perhaps the OP or another contributor would like to have a crack?
